# Convert Time to UTC

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timepicker that allows the user to select a time. If they select `7:00pm` how can I convert that to UTC 24H time?

If there is already an answer to this question and someone could direct me to it that would be great.

Comment: Have you checked out the API of your timechecker? It most likely includes using 24h time!

Comment: how do you know the time zone?

Comment: What timechecker are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged `JavaScript` and `jQuery`, I could guess you are using https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery? If so, try calling `getTime` method:

```
$('#my-timeicker-id').getTime(); // returns Javascript Date object
```

Check for your timepicker's API (e.g. https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#methods) for more.

--

In case you are using your own timepicker, you will have to implement it yourself. For learning purposes great, go for it! Otherwise don't reinvent the wheel and pick an existing solution.

Comment: Thanks, `$('#startTime').timepicker('getTime', new Date());` is exactly what I needed